# Unsupported Compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

This is the error I'm getting on the CMake GUI:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Config.cmake:106 (message):
  Unsupported compiler
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/cygwin/home/sfml-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/cygwin/home/sfml-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I'm not sure what causes this. I clicked "Configure" and that is what happened.

This is line 20:

```
# include the configuration file
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Config.cmake)
```

I'm new to CMake so I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Show us line 106 of cmake/Config.cmake

Comment: @hllnll `message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported compiler")`

Comment: @hllnll For some reason the CMake `if` statements are failing and it's going to the else statement which executes that command.

Comment: @user2030677 Are they failing, or are you actually attempting something which, as noted by the error message, is not supported? If it's not supported, and you'd like to actually understand what's going on, do ask, but it doesn't seem like you're interested in that at all. It seems like you just want the magic incantation to make it work. If so, that's really not what SO is for.

Comment: @hvd This is the first time I using CMake. The tutorial I'm following says to go to the GUI version, set the source directory and the binary directory, and then click configure. That's what I did and I got this error.

Comment: @user2030677 It does seem as if you've picked a project that simply doesn't support Cygwin, though. Does the tutorial you're using really say to use Cygwin, and to use that specific project? If not, you might want to use the non-Cygwin Windows version of cmake, and/or the project recommended by that tutorial.

Comment: @hvd I'm trying to build SFML code. I told CMake to generate MinGW makfile files (I also tried Codeblock cmake files). After reading the below answer, I took the `sfml-build` directory and changed it to a directory outside the Cygwin directory, but I still get the same error. And I don't know what you mean by "non-Cygwin version of cmake".

Comment: @user2030677 I mean that you shouldn't attempt to build this in Cygwin if it's not supported, but in Windows without Cygwin. Possibly with MinGW, possibly with Microsoft's compiler, whatever is supported. I don't know how you set up your environment since there's very little relevant information in your question, but if you installed cmake through Cygwin's installer, don't use that version. If the compiler in your PATH variable is one you got through Cygwin, don't use that compiler. If you're starting cmake through the Cygwin shell, just to be safe, don't do that either.

Comment: Perhaps some other time, but it's past midnight here, no time to be continuing this. :) Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFML doesn't support cygwin at the moment. [ref](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/140)

Comment: Alright, so I change the directory of where the binaries go (outside the cygwin directory) and I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: How does CMake even figure out your compiler anyway? I could have multiple compilers that I use, so how does that work?

Comment: There are many ways cmake can figure out which compiler it is. There's the `-v` option to start with.